# Generate a string with specific values in a range of cells in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

For example, I have 4 cells in the worksheet "data" 
with some data like bellow

```
 ----------------------------
 Param1|Param2|Param3|Param4|
 ----------------------------
 Value1|Value2|Value3|Value4|
```

And I put a button in this same workbook to generate a string with these values 
following this specific format (illustrative):

```
cmd.exe "-Value1-Value2-Value3-Value4-"
```

But I need to put this generated string in many cells in another worksheet according 
a specific conditions related with value in other cell, for example

```
-----------------------------------------------------
description | lorem ipsun lorem ipsun lorem ipsun lor|
------------------------------------------------------
command     | cmd.exe "-Value1-Value2-Value3-Value4-"|
------------------------------------------------------
description2| abra cadabra                           |
------------------------------------------------------
command     | cmd.exe "-Value1-Value2-Value3-Value4-"|
------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to put a generated string only in the lines that A1 cell has the value "command"

Could some one help with this issue contributing with some vba code? I'm not a lazy gui but I guess more simple and effective to ask in a specialized forum than try to found it in a mess websites, and for it's a challenge to solve this rapidly

Thanks so much

Comment: I'm not clear what you need. Can you show an example of what the data looks like in raw format and what you want the result to look like?

Comment: What is it you are asking? You can just define something with IF and then concatenate the cells as you like and the drag that formula down all rows and done. I cannot see the question yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some (non-working!) skeleton code to get you started:

```
Sub Fill_In_These_Cells

    Dim InsertThis as string
    InsertThis = _
        activeworksheet.range("Value1'sRange") & "-" & _
        activeworksheet.range("Value2'sRange") & "-" & _
        activeworksheet.range("Value3'sRange") & "-" & _
        activeworksheet.range("Value4'sRange")

    Dim OutputRange as string
    OutputRange= "A1:B4"
    Dim i as integer
    For i = 1 to 4
        if activeworksheet.cells(i,1).value="Command" then _
            activeworksheet.cells(i,2).value=InsertThis
    Next i
End Sub
```

<strike>I many not what to know the answer, but</strike> Why are you putting command lines into an Excel file in the first place? And why are you mixing them up with other text as well?

#### Edit

Somehow, I was awake enough to write psuedo-code this morning, but not enough to complete that sentence.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I need this because I'm making a plan test sheet and according with the cenario in need to put the related command with the correct parameters. I need just this kind off code to start my work. It's incredible how is easy to get help with good and smart people in stackoverflow. Thx a lot!

Comment: No problem.  Don't forget to green-check the best answer to your question :)